# Jquery not working in only ie8, all other browsers work fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I am trying to load some data using Ajax.
In IE 9 and all other browser works fine.
But in IE8 it always goes to catch. I don't why it always fire an exception.

Here is my code.

```
var SyncResponseText = "";

var WrapedRequestObject = JSON.stringify(RstClientServerDTO);


try {
    SyncResponseText = eval($.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        url: "../../ApplicationServiceHandler/ClientRequestHandler.ashx",
        data: WrapedRequestObject,
        timeout: 240000,
        dataType: "json",
        async: IsAssync,
        success: function (msg) {

//                if (msg == false) {
//                    window.location.href = window.location.href;
//                }
//                else {
                SuccessCallBack(msg);
//                }

        }, // function (data) { alert('success') },
        error: function (xhr, textstatus, error) { ErrorCallBack(xhr, textstatus,         error) } // { alert('error') }
    }).responseText);
}
catch (Exception) {
    SyncResponseText = Exception.get_Message();
}

return SyncResponseText;
```

Comment: Why are you `eval`ing that whole thing? That seems crazy to me.

Comment: +1 I agree `eval` does not make sense.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `eval`. That part of your code makes no sense.